# What's the difference between 僕等,　我々, 僕たち, and お互い?

Tags: politeness, pronouns

As I read more Japanese texts, I’m finding there are a lot of ways to say “us.” Are there any contextual differences or differences in politeness level between 僕等, 我々, 僕たち, and お互い?

Comment: 俺たち、僕たち、私たち、わたくしたち have the politeness level differences of the corresponding words without -たち.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have a different nuance, and お互い doesn't mean "us" but "each other".

僕たち and 僕等 are almost the same, I feel 僕等 is a bit casual. 我々 is a bit exaggerated, so it is not often used in daily conversation but in lofty and exaggerated speeches.